# Pass PHP Value Through Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I'm currently using the code below to successfully convert OS GRid References to Lat & Lon co-ordinates. This is done via a click event on a button on my html form.

```
function converttolatlng() {
    var gr = document.getElementById('osgridref').value;

    var osgb = new GT_OSGB();


    if (osgb.parseGridRef(gr)) {
        var wgs84 = osgb.getWGS84();

        document.getElementById('osgb36lat').value = wgs84.latitude;
        document.getElementById('osgb36lon').value = wgs84.longitude;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('osgb36lat').value = "n/a";
        document.getElementById('osgb36lon').value = "n/a";
    }

}
```

I am now wanting to introduce some OS Grid References (approx 22,000), from an external xml file that I want to convert before uploading the information to a mySQL database, (and hence wouldn't go through the normal form 'click' event), but I'm really not sure how to do it.

Could someone perhaps please show me how I would bypass the need for a 'click' event and perform the conversion automatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and you're really just looking to avoid having to click a button, you can simply call your function in a `<script>` at the bottom of your HTML. The script will be executed as soon as the browser renders it, so as long as the necessary elements are already on the page above it and the XML is loaded, it should work fine.

```
<!-- after most of your HTML, but before the closing <body> -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
  converttolatlng();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you need the full page loaded and have some external dependencies loaded by scripts that need to be in place, use the `window.onload` property inside the HTML `<head>` tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.onload = converttolatlng();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. Ideally I'd like to bypass the HTML form completely if I can. That way it can be run as a scheduled job in the hours where users of my website will be very low. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to do this (and to learn a tool that is super useful in the future) is to use an ETL tool like [Pentaho Kettle](http://community.pentaho.com/). This is a visual tool that you can connect to your DB and to your XML file, perform the Step transformations, then hit run. It will do all of the conversion for you.

If you need, you can use the OSGB java library in Pentaho to do the conversion for you, but you can also use Javascript libraries. Pentaho's documentation is a little lacking and it does take a little getting use to, but once you figure it out, it speeds up any ETL project you might have to taking just a few minutes instead of hours.

Alternately, if the OSGB library isn't available in PHP, I would just run it as a loop through Javascript and using jQuery.Json function, pass the results to PHP to be written to the DB. That way you can pass asynchronous objects and only have to deal with those transformations / DB writes that fail.

Check [PHPCoord](http://www.jstott.me.uk/phpcoord/)